# How does Type.Attributes of C# work?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

So `System.Type` has an instance method called [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.attributes.aspx).

```
public TypeAttributes Attributes { get; }
```

which returns an `enum` of type [`TypeAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes.aspx). Here are some members of this enum:

```
public enum TypeAttributes {
    AnsiClass = 0,
    Class = 0,
    AutoLayout = 0,
    NotPublic = 0,
    Public = 1,
    NestedPublic = 2,
    NestedPrivate = 3,
    NestedFamily = 4,
    NestedAssembly = 5,
    NestedFamANDAssem = 6,
    VisibilityMask = 7,
    NestedFamORAssem = 7,
    SequentialLayout = 8,
    ExplicitLayout = 16,
    LayoutMask = 24,
...
}
```

But on the other hand, `Type` class has provides too many properties for most of the stuff appear in this enum:

- `IsPublic`
- `IsClass`
- `IsNestedFamANDAssem`
- `IsAutoLayout`
- `...`

So what exactly `Type.Attributes` is for? I guess it is not a bitmasked value, since it is an enum and it returns only a single member of enum. And this is not a static property on `Type` class,so what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type.Attributes` is a bitmasked value. It even [says so in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes.aspx).

`enum`s are commonly used as Flag data types by decorating them with the `Flags` attribute.

And those  properties of `Type`, like `IsPublic`, `IsClass` etc. just check those flags and return a boolean value. You can see it yourself by looking at the definitions using reflector.

`IsPublic`, for example does something like this:

```
public bool IsPublic {
    get {
        return ((this.Attributes & TypeAttributes.VisibilityMask) == TypeAttributes.Public);
    }
}
```

Not all properties of `Type` necessarily represent one of the flags though (like `IsEnum`).

Comment: Why does it keep it a meaningless enum rather than making it an `int`?

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan - what do you mean "meaningless enum"? How would it being an `int` make it *more* meaningful?

Answer (score 2):

> I guess it is not a bitmasked value

You guess wrong. It's marked as [`FlagsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx):

> Indicates that an enumeration can be treated as a bit field; that is, a set of flags.

As you indicate, many of these are also available as properties. So, why is it exposed? Well, firstly, because it's the natural representation of this information. The properties (e.g. `IsPublic`) just hide the bit testing for you. And secondly, sometimes it's a more convenient value to pass around than an array of booleans.

Answer (score 1):

It is bitmasked value where portions of the value represent partiular properties of the Type -

- `myType.Attributes & TypeAttributes.VisibilityMask` gives you one of several Public/NonPublic/NestedPublic... values from the enum
- `myType.Attributes & TypeAttributes.LayoutMask` gives you layout type (Sequential/Explicit/default)

and so on.